# How to make arbitrary "sections" of a table in HTML that are correctly spaced?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble making a table which has arbitrarily sectioned off parts (by using borders on certain cells). I really can't explain this much better besides just showing you what I mean. I tried using a `div` in each table cell which had a left and right `padding` value of `10px`, but this causes other problems. You will see what I am trying to do and why there are problems here:

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid black
}
th {
  background-color: white;
}
td, th {
padding: 2px
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
}
td {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
td .inner {
  margin: -1px 0px;
}
.inner {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th style="border: 2px solid black;" rowspan="2">
      Header
    </th>
    <th colspan="3">
      Header #2
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 2px solid black; background-color: white;" colspan="3">Header subtitle</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Horizontal Header</th>
    <td>
      <div class="inner">
        foo
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">
      <div class="inner">
        bar
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">
      <div class="inner">
        dog
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">Horizontal Header 2</th>
    <td style="border-bottom: 2px solid black; border-right: 2px solid black;">
      <div class="inner">
        foo
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inner">
        bar
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inner">
        dog
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">Horizontal Header 3</th>
    <td style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">
      <div class="inner">
        foo
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inner" style="border-left: 2px solid black; border-top: 2px solid black;">
        bar
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="border-top: 2px solid black;">
      <div class="inner">
        dog
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Horizontal Header 4</th>
    <td>
      <div class="inner">
        foo
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inner">
        bar
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="inner">
        dog
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0f82dg4r/.

Comment: It's unclear what is supposed to have a border and what isn't

Comment: @EternalHour there is supposed to be a section around foo in row 3, and bar and dog in row 2.

Comment: Do you want to make a border only on few cells and not on others? I don't understand what are you really asking for!

Comment: @SaymoinSam I am trying to section off some parts of the table (not rows or columns) as seen in the code.

Comment: @TigerGold What do you mean by section off some parts of the table?!

Comment: @SaymoinSam did you look at the demo? just mark off with a border basically. just an aesthetic thing

Comment: @TigerGold for all cells?, I don't understand sorry. can you draw an image to what you want to do, as they say, a picture worth 1000 words